# jQuery: Finish dragging without triggering click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, clickable

I am trying to set up the following page where:

1. If you click the button, you can see a div.
2. If you click the div, you can see the next div.
3. If you move the button, there is no »click« (desired behaviour)

The problem I am having is that if you move the div, the next div appears - this is not what I want. The "next div" should not be displayed after a drag event finishes on it.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").draggable({
    stack: 'div',
    containment: "body"
  });
});

$('#button').on('mouseup', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
    // click function
    $("#content").toggle();
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#content").draggable({
    stack: 'div',
    containment: "body"
  });
});

let containers = $('.trip').hide();
let firstContainer = containers.first().show();

containers.on('click', function() {
  //Get current element and next sibling
  let elem = $(this);
  let next = elem.next('.trip');

  //Does sibling exist?
  if (next.length) {
    next.show();
  } else {
    firstContainer.show();
  }
  elem.hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.trip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Button</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="trip">div 1</div>
  <div class="trip">div 2</div>
  <div class="trip">div 3</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to solve this? :)
(a possible problem is also that pure JavaScript is mixed with jQuery)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem to solve here is in distinguishing a regular `click` event on `#content`, from other "click like events" that are also triggered during completion of the element being dragged.

You're code currently has a method of doing that which you could re purpose for the desired behaviour:

```
if (! $(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
   /* This was a "regular click event"
}
```

So in the case of your code, you could revise it as follows:

```js
$(function() {

  /* Combine on ready logic into one place */

  $("#button").draggable({
    stack: 'div',
    containment: "body"
  });
  
  $("#content").draggable({
    stack: 'div',
    containment: "body"
  });
  
  /* Hide all trip elements except for first */
  $('.trip', '#content').not(':first').hide();
});

$('#button').on('mouseup', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
    $("#content").toggle();
  }
});

$('#content').on('mouseup', function() {

  /* Reuse same logic in #button mouseup handler */
  if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {

      /* 
      If content element if not dragging, treat mouse up as conclusion
      of click event and rotate visibility of trip elements like this
      */
      let trip = $('.trip:visible', '#content');
      let next = trip.next().length === 0 ? 
          $('.trip:first', '#content') : trip.next();
      
      trip.hide();
      next.show(); 
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.trip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Button</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="trip">div 1</div>
  <div class="trip">div 2</div>
  <div class="trip">div 3</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"` consider fixing that so we could use the live demo, thanks.

Comment: @DacreDenny I have tears in my eyes! Thank you sooooooo much! One last question: Does that draggable thing work on mobile phones too?

Comment: @DacreDenny Ok, I checked it: It does not work. Why? :(

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan you're welcome - glad I could help :) mobile phones may be a little tricky - let me know if this works for you on mobile as is - if not I can try help you further :)

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan it seems like there is limited support for mobile with jqueryui however I found this which seems to work better on mobile - would it be an option for you? https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Mobile-Drag-Drop-Plugin-jQuery.html

Comment: @DacreDenny Ahhhh now I figured it out: The jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js has to be uploaded directly to the server. I don't know why, but then it works.
Wish you all the best. Actually you live in New Zealand? You have all the best! :) ;)

Comment: @DacreDenny Same moment! :D Hm. What would you recommend?

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan hi again - if jqueryui is working for you on mobile I'd probably stick with that as there's wider community support for it. I'm in New Zealand, for now at least :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny Say Hi to the Kiwis from mee! :D Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan haha they're pretty hard to find but will do - all the best with your project :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny May I ask you another question, Kiwi neighbor? I have now three buttons with different content. In principle, it works. But I have z-index problems. The last object in the code is always on top. But the last clicked or moved object should be on top. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yep, it will probably involves a bit of extra css and extension to your script - if you would like to send me a link to a new question for this problem I'll be happy to help :)

Comment: @DacreDenny I tried to minify the code and was a bit slow, sorry! Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351370/i-have-a-z-index-problem-with-draggable-divs

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan just posted this for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351542/8526705

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you need is this bit of readable code,

- Assign a class `.draggable` to all your draggable elements
- Use the new class as `stack: '.draggable'`
- Register click to your `'#container'`, not on your `.trip` elements
- Use only one Event, the `"click"` one:
- Hide all `.trip` but first using CSS `.trip~.trip {display:none;}`

```js
jQuery( $ => {

  const $cont = $('#content');
  const $bttn = $('#button');
  const $trip = $('.trip');
  const tripL = $trip.length;
  let   i = 0;

  $('.draggable').draggable({stack:'div', containment:'body'});
  
  $bttn.on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) $cont.toggle();
  });

  $cont.on('click', function() {
    $trip.eq(++i % tripL).show().siblings($trip).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
html, body { height:100%; margin:0;}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.trip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.trip ~ .trip {display: none;}
```

```html
<!-- PS: Add class="draggable" to draggable elements -->

<div id="button" class="draggable">Button</div>
<div id="content" class="draggable">
  <div class="trip" id="a">div 1</div>
  <div class="trip" id="b">div 2</div>
  <div class="trip" id="c">div 3</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

For more contents see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351517/383904

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. The last moved or clicked object should always be on top. Is that possible with your code?

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan Sure, I removed accidentally the `stack:'div',` that handles the z-index. I've added it back :)

Comment: Ok, interesting! Would that solve my »new problem« too? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351370/i-have-a-z-index-problem-with-draggable-divs