# JQuery: z-index ordering with draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

In the following code I have:

1. divs that pop up when you click the corresponding buttons
2. if you drag them around, the (last) active object should be on top

Currently my code doesn't work as expected where the last active element is bought to the front. I am trying to create an extensible solution where there can be about five or so more buttons later with different content.

Also, is there a way to let the divs pop up near to the buttons that they are shown from? If I drag the button before I clicked it, the distance is a bit big.

My current attempt looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
 /* Combine on ready logic into one place */
 $("#button-one").draggable({
  stack: 'div',
  containment: "body"
 });
 $("#content-one").draggable({
  stack: 'div',
  containment: "body"
 });
 /* Hide all trip elements except for first */
 $('.trip', '#content-one').not(':first').hide();
});
$('#button-one').on('mouseup', function() {
 if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
  $("#content-one").toggle();
 }
});
$('#content-one').on('mouseup', function() {
 /* Reuse same logic in #button mouseup handler */
 if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
  /* 
  If content element if not dragging, treat mouse up as conclusion
  of click event and rotate visibility of trip elements like this
  */
  let trip = $('.trip:visible', '#content-one');
  let next = trip.next().length === 0 ? $('.trip:first', '#content-one') : trip.next();
  trip.hide();
  next.show();
 }
});
$(function() {
 $("#button-two").draggable({
  stack: 'div',
  containment: "body"
 });
});
$('#button-two').on('mouseup', function() {
 if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
  // your click function
  $("#content-two").toggle();
 }
});
$(function() {
 $("#content-two").draggable({
  stack: 'div',
  containment: "body"
 });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: inherit;
cursor: default;
}

#content {
max-width: 100vw;
height: 150vh;
}

#one {
left: 5%;
top: 5%;
position: absolute;
}

#button-one {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: cyan;
position: absolute;
}

#content-one {
display: none;
cursor: all-scroll;
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}

.trip {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}

#two {
left: 15%;
top: 15%;
position: absolute;
}

#button-two {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: darkgrey;
position: absolute;
}

#content-two {
display: none;
cursor: all-scroll;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div id="one">
<div id="button-one">Button 1</div>

<div id="content-one">
<div class="trip">div 1</div>
<div class="trip">div 2</div>
<div class="trip">div 3</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
<div id="button-two">Button 2</div>
<div id="content-two">Hey</div>
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: And what should happen with the content when the content is open and one starts to drag the button around?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan In this case, the content should stay at the current position and the button should be on top of all the objects. Only if the button gets clicked, the content should be hided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer of mine to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351058/383904) - with some modifications I'd do it like:

- Use `data-*` attribute to store the target *content* selector ID
- Use `Event.clientX` / Y - to get the click coordinates
- Use `.css({left: X, top: Y})` to place your content
- Place all your elements inside the same parent to account for the problematic `z-indexing` and help `stack: '.draggable',` do its job

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $drag = $('.draggable').draggable({
    stack: '.draggable',
    containment: 'body'
  });

  // Fix out-of-containment glitch
  $($drag.draggable('option').containment).on('mouseleave', () => $drag.trigger('mouseup')); 
  
  let z = 10; // Contents zIndex (will increment on content toggle)

  $('.button').on('click', function(ev) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) return;
    $($(this).data('content')).css({left: ev.clientX, top: ev.clientY, zIndex: ++z}).toggle();
  });

  $('.content').on('click', function() {
    const $trip = $(this).find('.trip'), tripL = $trip.length;
    this._count |= 0;
    $trip.eq(++this._count % tripL).show().siblings($trip).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.button {
  width: 30vh;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.content {
  width: 45vh;
  height: 45vh;
  display: none;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.trip~.trip {
  display: none;
}

[data-content="#content-two"] {background: aquamarine;}
#content-two {background: fuchsia;}
```

```html
<div class="button draggable" data-content="#content-one">Toggle one</div>
<div class="content draggable" id="content-one">
  <div class="trip">ONE 1</div>
  <div class="trip">ONE 2</div>
  <div class="trip">ONE 3</div>
</div>

<div class="button draggable" data-content="#content-two">Toggle two</div>
<div class="content draggable" id="content-two">
  <div class="trip">TWO 1</div>
  <div class="trip">TWO 2</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems that it works fine! 
But: If I click for example »Toggle one«, the »ONE 1« should be on the top of all other objects. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan of course, simply change to `stack: '.draggable',` and in CSS set your `.content` to be initially`z-index:1;` :)

Comment: Hm ok. If I click »Toggle two« and afterwards »Toggle one«, the »ONE 1« is not on top, but it should.

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan take a look. Simply introduce an incrementable variable `z` and use it as `zIndex`

Comment: »incrementable variable«?  Sorry, I started coding a few weeks ago and I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: See the `let z = 10` - It's telling your program to set initially a zIndex to 10, than inside the `.css()` method there's the `zIndex: ++z`, the `++z` constantly increments the `z` by one. @LinaMcClanahan - If any part of the code is not understandable, feel free to ask.

Comment: Crazy guy, what time is it in Croatia? :D Learned a lot with your help, thanksss!

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan 5:00 AM :) you're welcome. We're all learning something new every day. I'm also learning from your questions and Dacre's answers - There's a multitude of ways to approach a problem, programming is an art ;) Happy coding

Comment: Best time! :)
I just checked both codes and I guess yours works a bit better. There is only one thing that irritates me: Sometimes, when I stopped dragging, the last dragged div still moves around with the mouse position. Why?

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan just updated my answer to resolve that - hope that helps!

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan That's caused when the mouse exits the window and you release the click. The DOM did not registered such event, therefore when you reenter - the program acts as if you're still dragging the element. Simply listen if the mouse exits your `.draggable` elements and trigger a `"mouseup"`. - See my  edit

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the order behaviour you're after, I would suggest some changes to your HTML structure. What you want to aim for is a "flat" HTML structure so that draggable elements (ie those that are currently nested in `#one` and `#two`) can be z-ordered relative to one another (ie in the same containing element/DIV).

With that done, you could then use the `start` event hook on `draggable()` to set element that's "currently on top". A simple way to do that would be to introduce a CSS class that sets the `z-index` property.

To position the draggable near the button being clicked, you can use JQuerys [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method to get the top/left coordinates of the button being clicked. You can then pass those directly to the `css()` method of the draggable element like this:

```
  /* Position of this button */
  const position = $(buttonElement).position();

  /* Position target near the button with slight offset */
  draggableElement.css({
    left : position.left + 10,
    top : position.top + 10
  });
```

The following revisions to your code should do the trick:

```js
/* 
  Helper function assigns the element as "top most" element
  relative to other elements
  */
function setToTop(element) {

  var zIndexMax = 0;

  $('.content, .button').each(function(i, elem) {

    var zIndex = Number.parseInt($(elem).css('z-index'));
    
    zIndex = Number.isNaN(zIndex) ? 0 : zIndex;

    zIndexMax = Math.max(zIndexMax, zIndex);     
  });
  
  element.css({
    zIndex: zIndexMax + 1
  });
}

$(function() {

  /* Prevent drag from continuing after mouse leaves document */
  $(document).mouseleave(function() {
    $(document).trigger("mouseup")
  });

  $(".content, .button").draggable({
    helper: "original",
    containment: "body",
    start: function(event, ui) {

      /* 
      ui.helper is the element that we're starting to drag 
      */
      setToTop(ui.helper);
    }
  });

  $('.trip').not(':first').hide();
});

$('.button').on('mouseup', function() {

  /* Cause clicked button to come to front */
  setToTop($(this));

  if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {

    var toggleTarget = $(".content" + $(this).data("target"));

    toggleTarget.toggle();

    if (toggleTarget.is(':visible')) {

      /* Cause newly toggled element to be visible on top */
      setToTop(toggleTarget);

      /* Position of this button */
      const position = $(this).position();

      /* Position target near the button with slight offset */
      toggleTarget.css({
        left: position.left + 10,
        top: position.top + 10
      });
    }
  }
});

$('.content').on('mouseup', function() {

  if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {

    let trip = $('.trip:visible', this);
    let next = trip.next().length === 0 ? $('.trip:first', this) : trip.next();
    trip.hide();
    next.show();
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: inherit;
  cursor: default;
}

#content {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 150vh;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.content.one {
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

.content.two {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.trip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  left: 15%;
  top: 15%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

#one {
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div id="one" class="button" data-target=".one">Button 1</div>
  <div id="two" class="button" data-target=".two">Button 2</div>

  <div class="content two">Hey</div>

  <div class="content one">
    <div class="trip">div 1</div>
    <div class="trip">div 2</div>
    <div class="trip">div 3</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

#### Update

To prevent glitchcy drag behaviour continuing after the mouse leaves the document during a drag you can do this:

```
/* 
  Helper function assigns the element as "top most" element
  relative to other elements
*/
function setToTop(element) {

  var zIndexMax = 0;

  $('.content, .button').each(function(i, elem) {

    var zIndex = Number.parseInt($(elem).css('z-index'));        
    zIndex = Number.isNaN(zIndex) ? 0 : zIndex;
    zIndexMax = Math.max(zIndexMax, zIndex);     
  });

  element.css({
    zIndex: zIndexMax + 1
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank youuu @DacreDenny! Works fine. Do you also have an idea for that distance thing?

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan sure - just added that :)

Comment: <marquee style="font-size: 99999999vh; color: red;">Aaaah!!!! I am so happy now! Thaaanks! </marquee>

Comment: Hi again, the reason why I wrote that Rokos code works better was the following problem: For example if you click »Button 2«, then »Button 1«, then you bring the »Hey«-div to top, then the »Button« and then the »Hey« again, the z-index works not correctly. Do you have a solution for that? :)

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan ah right - sorry I wasn't following your convo above very closely - I just made a minor tweak, adding `setToTop($(this))` to the start of the `mouseup` event - does that work as required now?

Comment: Thanks! There arise still some strange z-index positions ...
The position of the objects on top is right, but the objects below reorder sometimes.

Comment: @LinaMcClanahan ohh , I see what you mean - just fixed that. Does this recent update help?